# estou com problemas para sincronizar a execução desse programa -- JS, promise, async and await

Tags: javascript, microsoft-excel, arquivo, promises, async-await

Gente, eu estou com uma dúvida, eu gostaria de ler uma planilha do Excel, armazenar seu conteúdo em uma variável e depois exibir na tela. Entretanto o método que lê o arquivo -- parseExcel -- ocorre de modo assíncrono, então o programa segue o fluxo e eu não consigo ter acesso a varável com o texto do arquivo.
Abaixo a função que lê o arquivo, a função que quero armazenar a informação e saída no console.

async parseExcel() {

```
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
            type: 'binary'
        });
        var dadosToJson = [];
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
            // Here is your object
            var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
            var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
            dadosToJson.push(json_object);
            //console.log(json_object);
        })

        console.log(dadosToJson)
        return dadosToJson;

    }

  reader.onerror = function(ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    };

   reader.readAsBinaryString(this.file)
       
};
```

lerArquivoJson(){

```
    var texto = this.parseExcel()
    texto.then( (res) => console.log(res))
```

}

saída
lerArquivoJson(): undefined

async parseExcel():  ["[{"Id Palavra":"3","Palavras ":"birthday","Signifi…,"Data Inserção":"1/16/21"},{"Palavras ":"3647"}]", "[]"]

Note que o método lerArquivoJson não espera o parseExcel

Edit: Encontrei uma solução:

class LeitorArquivoXLSX{

```
//no momento só aceita um único arquivo
constructor(file){
    this.file=file;
    this.idTable = "vocabularioView";
    this.data;
}

async parseExcel() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: 'binary'
            });
            var dadosToJson = [];
            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName) {
                // Here is your object
                var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
                dadosToJson.push(json_object);
            })
            resolve(dadosToJson);

        }

        reader.onerror = function (ex) {
            reader.abort();
            reject(console.warn(ex));
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(this.file)
    });
       
};



async xlsxToJson(){
    try {
        const fileContents = await this.parseExcel();
        this.data = fileContents;
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e.message)
    }finally {
        this.imprimeData();
    }
}

imprimeData(){
    jQuery('#xlx_json').val("fileContents: "+this.data);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Transforme toda sua espera em ASYNC, isso pode resolver o problema.

```
async function myName(){

 var texto = await this.parseExcel()
    texto.then( (res) => console.log(res))

}
```

Comment: Oi bruno, aconteceu uma coisa bem estranha, pois deu a seguinte resposta:
Tive esses dois erros:


LeitorArquivo.js:48 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at LeitorArquivo.parseExcel (LeitorArquivo.js:12)
    at LeitorArquivo.lerArquivoJson (LeitorArquivo.js:46)
    at LeitorArquivo.parseExcel (LeitorArquivo.js:15)


   
(3950) LeitorArquivo.js:47 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at LeitorArquivo.lerArquivoJson (LeitorArquivo.js:47)

Comment: Ola, desculpa a demora...aparentemente ele esperou de mais pela resposta. envia o condigo completo para eu ver.

Comment: Ola Bruno, peço desculpas pela demora, eu fiquei sem internet por esses dias. De qualquer modo eu agradeço a sua ajuda e digo que consegui resolver!

Eu segui o proposto por esse artigo: https://blog.shovonhasan.com/using-promises-with-filereader/ , e fiz com que a função parseExcel retornasse uma promisse, e depois a chamei co try-catch-finnaly